# Django application deployed in AWS Elastic BeanStalk but cannot access the website

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a `django based web application successfully in AWS Elastic Beanstalk`. Health is showing `OK`. And logs are also `fine`.

I have allowed `SSH, HTTP and HTTPS traffic` in inbound rules of Security group.

But still I am not able to access my website using `mysite.elasticbeanstalk.com` url.

I did ssh and saw that python process is up and running -

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-x ~]$ ps -aef | grep python
root      2707     1  0 May13 ?        00:05:00 /usr/bin/python2.7 /opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup
root      2816     1  0 May13 ?        00:00:15 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/supervisord --nodaemon -c /opt/python/etc/supervisord.conf
```

`netstat -tulpn` command is showing some process is listening on port 80 but I don't see any listening entry for port 443.

Here is my .ebextensions/django.config file -

```
container_commands:
  00_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
  02_fixture:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py loaddata site.yaml"
  03_oscar_countries:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py oscar_populate_countries"
    test: test ! -f /var/log/my-logs/.semaphore03
  99_oscar_countries_populated:
    command: "touch /var/log/my-logs/.semaphore03"`

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "myapp.settings"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: myapp/wsgi.py
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"`
```

How should I proceed and debug? I am stuck here.

Comment: There is probably something wrong in your `settings.py` . Please include it here.

Comment: Yes I found settings.py had a problem.
I set the following variables to False and it worked -
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False, 
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False, 
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY= False, 
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False